# Flow's "asLiveData()" will never be observed if postponeEnterTransition is called

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines, android-transitions

I want to wait until my data is ready before showing my views so that my SharedElementTransitions can be properly executed.

Unfortunately, with this code, `startPostponedEnterTransition` will never be called if `data` is a LiveData obtained from `Flow::asLiveData()`.

```kotlin
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        postponeEnterTransition()

        viewModel.data.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            adapter.setData(it)
            (view.parent as? ViewGroup)?.doOnPreDraw {
                startPostponedEnterTransition()
            }
        }
    }
```

What am I supposed to do so I can wait until my data is loaded before calling `startPostponedEnterTransition()`. I've tried a lot of things and nothing works.

Comment: That sounds like [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129035555) which is fixed in the [new state manager](https://link.medium.com/V8CwhFL9nbb) available in Fragment 1.3.0-alpha08 or higher. What version of Fragments are you using?

Comment: Did you try to define your observer in `onCreateView`?

Comment: @ianhanniballake oh my god thanks for letting me know. I was using 1.2.5. I will update to the latest alpha and see if it works!!!

Answer (score 0):

As [ianhanniballake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1676363/ianhanniballake) pointed out, updating to androidx Fragments 1.3-alpha08+ fixes this issue.